# Expanding widgets infinitely to a single side

Tags: html, css

Basically I have 2 main containers on the site a main section and right side bar for smaller widgets.  My goal is for the backgrounds of those widgets to move  infinitely to their respected sides without moving the actual contents within the widgets as well.

[image]
This picture shows what should happen instead of what the code shows to happen.

```css
@font-face { font-family: UbuntuG; src: url('ubuntu-fonts/Ubuntu-L.ttf'); } 
*{ box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
body { background-color: #fffff; }
h1 {
    color: #1d1d1d; font-family: UbuntuG; font-size: 30;
}
h2 {
    color: #1d1d1d; font-family: UbuntuG; font-size: 18;
}
p {
    color: white; font-family: Arial; font-size: 16;
}
td  {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    height: 48px;
    min-width:48px;
}
a {
      display: block;
      text-decoration: none;
   color: #1d1d1d;
   font-family: UbuntuG;
   font-size: 16;
     
}


ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #1d1d1d;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
li a:hover {
    background-color: #33d6ff; color: white;
}
.active {
    background-color: #00BFFF; color: white;
}


.selector {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
}
/*Top full width container*/
.FullWidthContainer{ width:100%}
/*Content Container With max-width:1200px for example*/
.MainContainer{max-width:1200px; width:100%; margin: 0px auto; }
/* content containre divided in left-75% and right-25%}*/
.left{ width:70%; padding:2%; float:left;}
.spacer{ width:2%; padding:2%; float:center}
.right{ width:28%; padding:2%; float:right}
.right img{ width:100%}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Radio</title>
    <meta content="??">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
    <style>
        table, th, td { border: 5px solid white; border-spacing: 0; color: #1d1d1d; font-family: Arial; font-size: 16; }
        h1 { color: white; font-family: UbuntuG; font-size: 30; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="FullWidthContainer" style=""><ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">Who are we?</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
 </ul></div>
  <!-- Start cssSlider.com -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="cssslider_files/csss_engine1/style.css">
  <!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" href="cssslider_files/csss_engine1/ie.css"><![endif]-->
  <!--[if lte IE 9]><script type="text/javascript" src="cssslider_files/csss_engine1/ie.js"></script><![endif]-->
   <div class="csslider1 autoplay ">
  <input name="cs_anchor1" id="cs_slide1_0" type="radio" class="cs_anchor slide">
  <input name="cs_anchor1" id="cs_slide1_1" type="radio" class="cs_anchor slide">
  <input name="cs_anchor1" id="cs_slide1_2" type="radio" class="cs_anchor slide">
  <input name="cs_anchor1" id="cs_play1" type="radio" class="cs_anchor" checked="">
  <input name="cs_anchor1" id="cs_pause1_0" type="radio" class="cs_anchor pause">
  <input name="cs_anchor1" id="cs_pause1_1" type="radio" class="cs_anchor pause">
  <input name="cs_anchor1" id="cs_pause1_2" type="radio" class="cs_anchor pause">
  <ul>
   <li class="cs_skeleton"><img src="cssslider_files/csss_images1/download.jpg" style="width: 100%;"></li>
   <li class="num0 img slide"> <img src="cssslider_files/csss_images1/download.jpg" alt="" title=""></li>
   <li class="num1 img slide"> <img src="cssslider_files/csss_images1/download_1.jpg" alt="" title=""></li>
   <li class="num2 img slide"> <img src="cssslider_files/csss_images1/download_2.jpg" alt="" title=""></li>
  <!-- </ul><div class="cs_engine"><a href="http://cssslider.com">http://cssslider.com</a> by cssSlider.com v2.1</div> -->
  <div class="cs_description">
   <label class="num0"></label>
   <label class="num1"></label>
   <label class="num2"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="cs_play_pause">
   <label class="cs_play" for="cs_play1"><span><i></i><b></b></span></label>
   <label class="cs_pause num0" for="cs_pause1_0"><span><i></i><b></b></span></label>
   <label class="cs_pause num1" for="cs_pause1_1"><span><i></i><b></b></span></label>
   <label class="cs_pause num2" for="cs_pause1_2"><span><i></i><b></b></span></label>
   </div>
  <div class="cs_arrowprev">
   <label class="num0" for="cs_slide1_0"><span><i></i><b></b></span></label>
   <label class="num1" for="cs_slide1_1"><span><i></i><b></b></span></label>
   <label class="num2" for="cs_slide1_2"><span><i></i><b></b></span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="cs_arrownext">
   <label class="num0" for="cs_slide1_0"><span><i></i><b></b></span></label>
   <label class="num1" for="cs_slide1_1"><span><i></i><b></b></span></label>
   <label class="num2" for="cs_slide1_2"><span><i></i><b></b></span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="cs_bullets">
   <label class="num0" for="cs_slide1_0"> <span class="cs_point"></span>
    <span class="cs_thumb"><img src="cssslider_files/csss_tooltips1/download.jpg" alt="" title=""></span></label>
   <label class="num1" for="cs_slide1_1"> <span class="cs_point"></span>
    <span class="cs_thumb"><img src="cssslider_files/csss_tooltips1/download_1.jpg" alt="" title=""></span></label>
   <label class="num2" for="cs_slide1_2"> <span class="cs_point"></span>
    <span class="cs_thumb"><img src="cssslider_files/csss_tooltips1/download_2.jpg" alt="" title=""></span></label>
  </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End cssSlider.com -->

    <div class="FullWidthContainer">
  <div class="MainContainer">
   <span style="background-color: #161616;" class="left"><center>
    <iframe height="400px" width="550px" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" src=https://hellodj.airtime.pro/embed/weekly-program></iframe>
   </center></span>
   <div style="background-color: #161616;" class="right">
    <iframe id="embed_player" frameborder="0" width="280" height="216" src="https://hellodj.airtime.pro/embed/player?stream=auto"></iframe>
   </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more about what you want to happen? Not sure what you're asking currently.

Comment: Fixed it ty for the info!